# How to get the current/active branch with LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: .net, git, libgit2sharp

So using LibGit2Sharp https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp you can walk through the branches like this

```
using (var repo = new Repository(@"path to .git"))
{
    foreach (var branch in repo.Branches)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(branch.Name);   
    }
}
```

But how do I get the current/active branch?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Branch.IsCurrentRepositoryHead` should do the trick.

I think `Repository.Head` will also do the same thing if you don't want to iterate through the branches...

Comment: In case it catches anyone else, because of how exact this property is, it will return false if you have checked out `Branch` but you are either behind or ahead of that branch on a fetched remote.

Comment: This function should not care at all about any remote repositories.  It literally does a string compare against the branch names.  If you think it does change depending on remote repositories, please file a bug report with a reproduction case.

Answer (score 2):

I think that, instead of going through the branches and checking whether each branch is the current head, the simplest approach is to directly get the branch name from the repository Head:

```
using (var repo = new Repository(@"path to .git"))
{
    var currentBranchName = repo.Head.FriendlyName;
}
```

You can then obtain the branch itself via

```
repo.Branches[currentBranchName]
```

Comment: You can just use the `Head` to get the branch: `repo.Head.Reference.TargetIdentifier`.