# How to get the current branch with LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: libgit2sharp

How do I get the branch for a specific directory even if this directory is not the root of the repo ? iow the equivalent of

`git branch --show-current`

(which works fine even in a subdirectory).

Following the answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12837311/12379), I did as follows, which works only in the root dir of the repo:

```
using (var git = new Repository("repo_root\subdir")) // throws if subdir
{
  return git.Head.FriendlyName;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops, found it:

```
using (var git = new Repository(
  LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Discover(@"repo_root\subdir")))
{
  return git.Head.FriendlyName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to self answer! Helped me out a lot